# Python: Skip a block of code (calculation) when certain condition is met without using "if" statements

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

I have this small block of code which I am trying to write better way since this one has a bunch of "if" statements. This is the small code of some big project. The problem is this: as the code runs, function "f", "g", or/and "k" can return None or numerical data. Whenever None value is returned, rest of the calculation has to get skipped since mathematical operations (which happens in those functions) cannot be done. I tried to rewrite the code using TRY/CATCH method, but couldn't make it work. I am trying to avoid "if" statements and rewrite concise way. I appreciate the help.

---

```
def f(output):
    #some code which computes output which be None or numerical
    return [output*1,2]
def g(Y):
    #some code which computes Y which be None or numerical
    return Y*3
def k(output):
  #some code which computes output which be None or numerical
  return output*4
def foutput():
  #some code which computes "value" which be None or numerical 
  value=2.0
  return 1.0*value


#####START
#some code
output=foutput()

if output is not None:
    print 'S1'
    [output,A]=f(output)
    if output is not None:
        print 'S2'
        [a,b,c,Y]=[1,2,3,k(output)]
        if Y is not None:
            print 'S3'
            A=g(Y)
        else:
            [Q,A,output]=[None,None,None]
    else:
        [Q,A,output]=[None,None,None]
else:
    [Q,A,output]=[None,None,None]
```

Comment: What didn't work about the try/except approach? (I assume you mean you had f, g, and k throw an exception rather than returning None, and put `[Q,A,output]=[None,None,None]` in the except block?)

Comment: You can 'standardize' function signatures and then have them executed one after another with simple check in-between, but in your case simple try/except should be more than enough - just have your functions raise a specific exception, then have your code execute linearly and surround it with a try/except block to capture 'non-standard' returns (e.g. if any of the functions returned `None`)

Answer (score 1):

Determine the error that would be raised in each step, then add those exceptions to a `try..except`. In this toy example, they're all `TypeError`, but I'll add `ValueError` as a demonstration:

```
def f(output):
    #some code which computes output which be None or numerical
    return [output*1,2]
def g(Y):
    #some code which computes Y which be None or numerical
    return Y*3
def k(output):
  #some code which computes output which be None or numerical
  return output*4
def foutput():
  #some code which computes "value" which be None or numerical 
  value=2.0
  return 1.0*value


output=foutput()

try:
    print 'S1'
    output, A = f(output)
    print 'S2'
    a, b, c, Y = 1, 2, 3, k(output)
    print 'S3'
    A = g(Y)
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    Q = A = output = None
else:
    Q = 'success' # if none of this fails, you might want a default value for Q
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution:

```
def compute():
    if f() is not None: print 'S1'
    else: return
    if g() is not None: print 'S2'
    else: return
    if k() is not None: print 'S3'
    else: return

compute()
```

There are still `if` statements, but they aren't confusingly nested as in your original code.

This uses the fact that when you `return` from a function, the rest of the function is skipped and computation in that function ends.